# How to force MVC action to do something specific

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Simply talking, ActionFilter is good to check something before executing the action. What is there to check the action execution result? Is there anything that can be applied after action has executed?

For clarity, I need to check whether `Session["UserID"]` is set after action has completed its execution.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @Tengiz: "I need to check" - for unit testing purposes? Or why do you need to check this?

Comment: I cannot accept answer until 8 minutes left (by the rules of stack overflow). Meanwhile I looked at the abstract ActionFilter class and found the answer really useful. Makes sense?

Comment: What do you want to happen when you check it?

Comment: I will throw an exception if false.

Comment: @Tengiz What will this achieve? Who will act on that exception?

Comment: Good question. Actually what I need to achieve is to use that session variable in some place after the action has executed. So I mark the action as it should set the session variable. This way, I will force action to set that. Sounds good?

Comment: @Tengiz No, not really. It sounds like you're confusing test-driven programming with error handling. This is an error you want to catch in design-time, not run-time. Otherwise, what good will the exception do? The normal way to "mark the action as it should set the session variable" is to create a programmatic test for it in the Test Project that was or wasn't created when you created your ASP.NET MVC project. This is all very easy to do with ASP.NET MVC, and it can certainly guarantee that your action method sets the session variable in a much more controlled fashion than an exception can.

Comment: @bzlm You are right in this point. But creating a unit test for the controller is not a good idea, because the project is for personal use only and I don't care about unit-testing that to be honest :-) But do you think I should not use action filter in this case too? if unit-test is not an option anyway?

Comment: @Tengiz I'm still wondering what will happen when the exception is thrown, and who will act upon it. :)

Comment: @bzlm let's say I use that information in the page view. That's an optional usage, meaning if it's not set, then the view can still work (e.g.: <%= Session["UserID"] == null ? defaultUserID : (int)Session["UserID"] %>... ). If considering Controller/Action/View, then this same view is used by different Controllers/Actions, and the View works anyway. In case of particular Controllers/Actions I want this view to take Sesson["UserID"] instead of the defaultUserID. But if I didn't throw an exception in this case, then I'd never notice that the Session["UserID"] was not set... Your thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `OnActionExecuted` in your `ActionFilter` to check after the action has executed. [More information from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuted.aspx). Example here:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext ctx) {
  base.OnActionExecuted(ctx);
  ctx.HttpContext.Trace.Write("Log: OnActionExecuted",
      "After " +
      ctx.ActionDescriptor.ActionName);
}
```

Comment: I will check this and get back to you if this works :-) thanks!